# Parameterized queries with psycopg2: SELECT from a Python list

Tags: python, psycopg2, prepared-statement

Given a large (~10,000) list of integers in Python, How do I efficiently `SELECT` all items from a table whose id is in the list?

I've tried:

```
>>> lst2
[{'id': 97600167}, {'id': 97600168}, {'id': 97611194}]
>>> cur.executemany("SELECT id, parent_id FROM my_table WHERE id=%(id)s", lst2)
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(97611194, 10020688), (None, None), (None, None)]
```

The second and third id (97600168, 97611194) do exist in the table.

Answer (score 8):

Using your example, use `where id in` and then pass a parameter which is a tuple of the id values you want to select:

```
>>> lst2
[{'id': 97600167}, {'id': 97600168}, {'id': 97611194}]
>>> ids = tuple(x['id'] for x in lst2)
>>> cur.execute("SELECT id, parent_id FROM my_table where id in %s",[ids])
```

Comment: Thanks, but It gives me a `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt` exception.

Comment: What version are you using? I tested this parameterization on `psycopg2.__version__ == 2.0.14` before posting. You did pass (a single item sequence of) a tuple of `int`s didn't you, as shown in my example?